# Update multiple column of a table from a single table in a single command in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have 2 tables, described bellow.

```
create table #tbl_1
    (
        nm varchar(20) not null,
        min_val float,
        max_val float,
        dept varchar(50)
    )

insert into #tbl_1(nm) values('A')  
insert into #tbl_1(nm) values('B')  
insert into #tbl_1(nm) values('C')

create table #tbl_2
    (
        nm varchar(20) not null,
        val float
    )

insert into #tbl_2 values('A', 10)
insert into #tbl_2 values('A', 20)
insert into #tbl_2 values('A', 30)
insert into #tbl_2 values('B', 50)
insert into #tbl_2 values('B', 40)
insert into #tbl_2 values('C', 15)
insert into #tbl_2 values('D', 60)
insert into #tbl_2 values('B', 65)
```

Now Update Operation:

```
update #tbl_1 set min_val=(select min(val) from #tbl_2 where #tbl_1.nm=#tbl_2.nm)
update #tbl_1 set max_val=(select max(val) from #tbl_2 where #tbl_1.nm=#tbl_2.nm)

select * from #tbl_1
drop table #tbl_1
drop table #tbl_2
```

In my real table #tbl_1 has 114 columns and they are updating from 17 different tables like #tbl_2. So when I am updating #tbl_1, I have to execute 113 SQL Statement. 
Is there any way that I can execute only 17 SQL Statement or 1 SQL Statement to update #tbl_1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the update using a join:

```
update t1
    set min_val = t2.minval,
        max_val = t2.maxval
    from #tbl_1 t1 join
         (select t2.nm, min(t2.val) as minval, max(t2.val) as maxval
          from #tbl_2 t2
          group by t2.nm
         ) t2sum
         on t1.nm = t2sum.nm
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd line set min_val = t2.minval, max_val = t2.maxval will be t2sum.minval, t2sum.maxval. Now its ok. Thanks.